# Converting XML to String[] help

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, writer

I'm having Trouble converting the contents of XML document to an int[] or string[]
I'm saving the x and y coordinates of 20 different picture boxes on the screen (For a jigsaw Puzzle Program) to an xml file, and are now trying to load the saved coordinates and update the jigsaw puzzle pieces to those saved locations.

Heres my code:

```
    XmlWriter XmlWriter1;
    XmlReader XmlReader1;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //-------------------------------------------------
        //Load Events
        //-------------------------------------------------
        SavedPositions = new int[40];
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    //Saves The Current Tile Locations To A Hidden XML File
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    public void SavePicPositionsXML()
    {
        using (XmlWriter1 = XmlWriter.Create("SavedPuzzle.xml"))
        {
            XmlWriter1.WriteStartDocument();
            XmlWriter1.WriteStartElement("MTiles");
            for (int i = 0; i < JigsawImgCount; i++)
            {
                XmlWriter1.WriteStartElement("Tile");
                XmlWriter1.WriteElementString("X",Convert.ToString(MTiles[i].Pic.Location.X));
                XmlWriter1.WriteElementString("Y",Convert.ToString(MTiles[i].Pic.Location.Y));
                XmlWriter1.WriteEndElement();
            }
            XmlWriter1.WriteEndElement();
            XmlWriter1.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Reads Text From A Hidden Xml File & Adds It To A String Array
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    private int ReadXmlFile(int Z)
    {
        XmlReader1 = XmlReader.Create("SavedPuzzle.xml");
        XmlReader1.MoveToContent();
        while (XmlReader1.Read())
        {

        }
        //    SavedPositions[B] = Convert.ToInt32(XmlReader1.Value.ToString());
        return SavedPositions[Z];
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------
    //Loads Saved Tile Positions From A Hidden Xml File
    //------------------------------------------------- 
    private void LoadPositionsXML()
    {
        G = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < JigsawImgCount; i++)
        {
            LineX = ReadXmlFile(G);
            LineY = ReadXmlFile(G + 1);
            MTiles[i].Pic.Location = new Point(LineX, LineY);
            G = G + 2;
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

Your `ReadXmlFile` method isn't doing anything really.

Consider using `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` instead of `XmlWriter` and `XmlReader`. They are a lot easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
           XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(@"D:/SavedPuzzle.xml");
        XmlNode topNode = document.GetElementsByTagName("MTiles")[0];
        foreach (XmlNode node in topNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            int X = Int32.Parse(node.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
            int Y = Int32.Parse(node.ChildNodes[1].InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Value cannot be null" in debug what exactly does this mean?

Comment: I modified the Code, check it out

Answer (score 0):

The following LinqToXML statement will extract all tiles into a list in the order they are stored in the document.

I'm assuming an XML file that looks like this:

```
<xml>
  <MTiles>
    <Tile>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>10</Y>
    </Tile>
    <Tile>
        <X>2</X>
        <Y>20</Y>
    </Tile>
    <Tile>
        <X>3</X>
        <Y>30</Y>
    </Tile>
    <Tile>
        <X>4</X>
        <Y>40</Y>
    </Tile>
  </MTiles>
</xml>
```

And this code will load it, and extract all the tiles into an enumerable list. Remember to put a `using System.Xml.Linq` at the top of the file and build against a recent enough framework (IIRC, it was introduced in .NET 3.5)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(/* path to the file, or use an existing reader */);
var tiles = from tile in doc.Descendants("Tile")
            select new
            {
                X = (int)tile.Element("X"),
                Y = (int)tile.Element("Y"),
            };
foreach (var tile in tiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tile: x={0}, y={1}", tile.X, tile.Y);
}
```

The output from the code above using the XML file I specified is:

```
Tile: x=1, y=10
Tile: x=2, y=20
Tile: x=3, y=30
Tile: x=4, y=40
```

**EDIT:**
If you just want all the `X`-values as an array of integers, the following LINQ query would work:

```
int[] allXValues = (from tile in doc.Descendants("Tile")
                    select (int)tile.Element("X")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Interesting this might work but how would i go about dumping all Tile X and Y values into one Int[] as thats how i call on the positions in my program.

Comment: Added a query that gets all X-values as an `int[]`. Or do you mean you want all X and all Y values into a single array? If so, why?

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that there is no definition for "root", i have added "using.system.xml.linq;" to the top, if it also helps this is in a form application.

Comment: @Mathew: Are you using .NET 3.5/C# 3 or newer? Linq2XML is not available in .NET 2. If you cannot use newer .NET then I'm afraid my answer is not going to help you.

Comment: Btw I just noticed that `Root` isn't really needed in the code.. You can do `doc.Descendants("...")` instead

Comment: And do you have a reference to System.Xml.Linq in your project?

Comment: Yes thats the first thing i did